# Issue with upsert: SQLAlchemy insert works, update doesn't

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

My session manager:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, scoped_session
from sqlalchemy.exc import SQLAlchemyError
import contextlib

class DatabaseSessionManager:
    def __init__(self, connection_string):
        self.engine = create_engine(connection_string)
        self.session_factory = sessionmaker(bind=self.engine)
        self.Session = scoped_session(self.session_factory)

    @contextlib.contextmanager
    def session_scope(self):
        """Provide a transactional scope around a series of operations."""
        session = self.Session()
        try:
            yield session
            session.commit()
        except SQLAlchemyError as e:
            session.rollback()
            raise
        finally:
            session.close()
```

the upsert:

```
def upsert(session, customer):
    try:
        # Attempt to find the customer by id
        existing_customer = session.query(Customer).filter_by(id=customer.id).first()

        if existing_customer:
            # Update existing customer
            for key, value in vars(customer).items():
                if hasattr(existing_customer, key) and value is not None:
                    setattr(existing_customer, key, value)
        else:
            # Create new customer
            session.add(customer)

    except SQLAlchemyError as e:
        print(f"Error occurred: {e}")
        session.rollback()
    finally:
        session.close()
```

When inserting an object with a key, which doesn't exist, the data is written to the database

```
from datetime import datetime
test_customer = Customer(
    id=6962763399483,  # Manually assign a unique ID
    first_name='Melanie',
    last_name='Dopp',
    email='john.doe@example.com',
    orders_count='9000',
    total_spent='19000',
    created_at=datetime.utcnow(),
    last_order_created_at=datetime.utcnow()  # Assign a relevant datetime or None
)
```

When I edit the object, without changing to key, the changes aren't committed. I also tried with a modified database manager class, using `__enter__`, `__exit__`

```
with dbm.session_scope() as session:
    print(session.query(Customer).filter_by(id=6962763399483).first().last_name)
# returns Ruby
```

My data:
[image]

What is going wrong here?

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: There is a lot going on here but what database are you using?  Did you mean "postgres" instead of "progress"?

Comment: yes, just corrected the tag, and posted the solution

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote my db code and now it works. The critical modification was using `session.merge`:

```
def upsert_customer(session: Session, customer: Customer):  
    try:
        # Check if the customer already exists
        existing_customer = (
            session.query(Customer).filter(Customer.id == customer.id).first()
        )

        if existing_customer:
            session.merge(customer)
        else:
            logger.info(
                f"Customer {customer.id} doesn't exist in database, creating a new record..."
            )
            session.add(customer)

        session.commit()
        logger.info(f"Customer {customer.id} saved successfully!")
    except SQLAlchemyError as e:
        logger.error(f"An error occurred: {e}")
        session.rollback()
        raise
    finally:
        session.close()

def db_session(store_name: str) -> contextlib._GeneratorContextManager[Session]:
    try:
        conn_str = PostgresConfig(store_name, Customer).conn_str
        engine = create_engine(conn_str)
        return db_connection(engine)
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(
            f"Failed to establish database connection for store {store_name}: {e}",
            exc_info=True,
        )
        raise


@contextlib.contextmanager
def db_connection(engine: Engine):
    session_factory = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    Session = scoped_session(session_factory)
    session = Session()

    try:
        yield session
        session.commit()
    except SQLAlchemyError as e:
        logger.error(f"Database error occurred: {e}")
        session.rollback()
        raise
    finally:
        session.close()
        logger.info("Database session closed")
```